# Rails why undefined local variable or method `new_dispute' for #<#<Class:0x007fec13d18678>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

i added dispute new link inside orders but rails log shows

since the dispute is associated with order in the model why still show undefined local variable or method?

> undefined local variable or method `new_dispute' for
>
> <#

someone know why?

```
view/_order.html.erb

        <ul>
     <li>Order: <b><%= order.transaction.transaction_id %></b></li>
      <li>seller:<%= order.seller_name %></li>
 <li><%=link_to"Create New Dispute", new_dispute %></li>
</ul>

disputer controller


class DisputesController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @order = current_user.cart.orders.find(params[:id])
    if current_user.address.blank?
      redirect_to edit_user_path
      flash[:error] = 'error'
    else
      @dispute = Dispute.new
    end
  end 
end

class Order < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_one :dispute


end


class Dispute < ActiveRecord::Base
  # attr_accessible :title, :body


  belongs_to :order
'

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `new_dispute_path`.

And read all about this stuff here :)

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#path-and-url-helpers